# Amazon SES Smtp much slower than Raw mails

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

Why is Amazon Simple Emailing Service Smtp mails 10 times slower than raw mails ?

The only difference is the raw mails are sent with the methods provided with the AWS SDK. The SMTP emails were sent using the the built in C# code to send emails (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient) which then points to the aws smtp end point.

This happens in a background service but the smtp is 10 times slower. Currently sending at a rate of something like 1 per second while our current quota should be 14 per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you Check TCP/IP Round Trip Time between your server and "the aws smtp end point"?
Use `ping` or `traceroute` to measure it

Sending email over SMTP without pipelining requires **at least**

- 3 RTT in case of reused SMTP connection (`MAIL FROM:`+`RCPT TO`+`DATA`).
- 7 RTT in case of one mail per one SMTP connection (+1 RTT for SMTP AUTH)

Possible fixes:

- reuse SMTP connection (many messages over single SMTP connection)
- use pipeling (sending commands before receiving pending replies
  but email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com does not advertise pipeling support in `ehlo` reply
- use a few parallel SMTP connections

Comment: The web server is an EC2 instance which is not in the same edge location as the default amazon smpt endpoint so I also suspected network latency could be the cause, strange still that the raw mails can be so much faster , I will investigate your suggestions thanx

Comment: Cached HTTP 1.1 connection introduces 1 RTT delay per request.